# vbs: Show all Folder subfolders with an iterative script?

Tags: vbscript

IS it possible to get all Subfolders (And the subfolders from the subfolders,...) of an Directory with an iterative script?

I already created it recursive but im not possible to do it iterative :/

Anyone an idea :O

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to implement the stack which a recursive Sub/Function gives you for free:

```
Dim sSDir : sSDir = "..."
walkDirIter goFS.GetFolder(sSDir)

Sub walkDirIter(oDir)
  Dim dicStack : Set dicStack = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim nCur     : nCur         = dicStack.Count
  Set dicStack(nCur) = oDir
  Do Until nCur >= dicStack.Count
     Dim oElm
     For Each oElm In dicStack(nCur).Files
         WScript.Echo oElm.Path
     Next
     For Each oElm In dicStack(nCur).SubFolders
         Set dicStack(dicStack.Count) = oElm
     Next
     nCur = nCur + 1
  Loop
End Sub ' walkDirIter
```

You could look at [this recursive approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10210862/603855) for context/comparison.

Comment: Thanks you :)
Good idea implementing it with a Stack :D