# Implementing vbs script for renaming filenames in folders and sub folders into hta for showing progress bar

Tags: vbscript, hta

```html
 Dim str
 set str = Wscript.Arguments

 str = InputBox("Enter the path of the files to be renamed as per e-ctd naming pattern")
 IF str = "" THEN Cancelled

 Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 Dim sSDir : sSDir = str

 walkDirIter goFS.GetFolder(sSDir)

 Sub walkDirIter(oDir)
 Dim dicStack : Set dicStack = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 Dim nCur     : nCur         = dicStack.Count
 Set dicStack(nCur) = oDir
 Do Until nCur >= dicStack.Count
    Dim oElm
    For Each oElm In dicStack(nCur).Files
  
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "apple") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "apple", "a1...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "ball") <> 0 Then
    sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "ball", "b2...")
    oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "cat") <> 0 Then
    sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "cat", "c3....")
    oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "dog") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "dog", "d4....")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "elephant") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "elephant", "e5...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "fan") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "fan", "f6...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "guitar") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "guitar", "g7...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "hat") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "hat", "h8....")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "ink") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "ink", "i9...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "jet") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "jet", "j10...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
 Next
 
    For Each oElm In dicStack(nCur).SubFolders
  Set dicStack(dicStack.Count) = oElm
    Next
     nCur = nCur + 1
 Loop
 
 End Sub
```

I was using a [vbs script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byhxor5xpFGVX051SGF2NUpzS0E/view?usp=sharing) for renaming files in folder and all the subfolders within and it worked properly for me (though its not the best way to write vbs scripts. I am trying to get better). Sometimes renaming files takes a lot of time as there are hundreds of files. So after searching I found that its better to implement the vbs script in hta to get a progress bar and better visuals. 
This is as close as I got to it:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title id="title">Rename</title>
  <HTA:APPLICATION ID="ProgressBar" APPLICATIONNAME="ProgressBar" SCROLL="no" MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no" />
  <SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
    Public x, y, MyTitle

     Sub Window_Onload
     window.resizeTo 436, 216
     y = 1
     x = 1
     MyTitle = " _ Rename"
    End Sub


     Sub Go

     Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

     objStartFolder = path.value

     Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

     Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

     For Each fil in colFiles

     y = y + 1

     Next

     For Each fil in colFiles

     Progress()

     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "apple") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "apple", "a1...")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "ball") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "ball", "b2...")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "cat") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "cat", "c3....")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "dog") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "dog", "d4....")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "elephant") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "elephant", "e5...")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "fan") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "fan", "f6...")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "guitar") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "guitar", "g7...")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "hat") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "hat", "h8....")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "ink") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "ink", "i9...")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "jet") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "jet", "j10...")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If

     Next

     ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(path.value)

     Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)

     For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders

     Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)

     Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

     For Each fil in colFiles

     y = y + 1

     Next

     For each fil in colFiles

     Progress()

     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "apple") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "apple", "a1...")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "ball") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "ball", "b2...")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "cat") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "cat", "c3....")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "dog") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "dog", "d4....")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "elephant") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "elephant", "e5...")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "fan") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "fan", "f6...")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "guitar") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "guitar", "g7...")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "hat") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "hat", "h8....")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "ink") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "ink", "i9...")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If
     If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "jet") < > 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "jet", "j10...")
     fil.Name = sName
     End If

     Next

     ShowSubFolders Subfolder

     Next

     End Sub

     Sub Progress
     x = x + 1
     document.Title = FormatPercent(x / y, 0) & MyTitle
     document.all.ProgBarText.innerText = x & "/" & y
     document.all.ProgBarDone.innerText = String(x, "_")
     document.all.ProgBarToDo.innerText = String(y - x, "_") & "|"
    If x = y Then
     document.all.ProgBarToDo.innerText = ""
    MsgBox "Done"
    window.close
     End If
     End Sub
  </SCRIPT>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#D7D7D7">

  Path:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="path">
  <br>

  <br>
  <!-- Basic buttons -->
  <input id="BtnGo" type="button" value="Go" onclick="Go">
  <br>
  <span id="ProgBarText"></span>
  <br>
  <span id="ProgBarDone" style="background-color: #3399FF"></span>
  <font color="#FFFFFF">
 <span id="ProgBarToDo"style="background-color: #C0C0C0"></span>
 </font>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem here is that this hta gives script error with syntax issue for `ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(path.value)` so I tried it by removing the SUBFOLDER part and running the hta like this:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title id="title">Rename</title>
  <HTA:APPLICATION ID="ProgressBar" APPLICATIONNAME="ProgressBar" SCROLL="no" MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no" />
  <SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
    Public x, y, MyTitle

     Sub Window_Onload
     window.resizeTo 436, 216
     y = 0
     x = 0
     MyTitle = " _ Rename"
    End Sub


     Sub Go

     Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

     objStartFolder = path.value

     Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

     Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

     For Each fil in colFiles

     y = y + 1

     Next
  
  
For Each fil in colFiles

Progress()
  
If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "apple") <> 0 Then
    sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "apple", "a1...")
    fil.Name = sName
End If
If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "ball") <> 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "ball", "b2...")
     fil.Name = sName
End If
If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "cat") <> 0 Then
     sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "cat", "c3....")
     fil.Name = sName
End If
If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "dog") <> 0 Then
    sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "dog", "d4....")
    fil.Name = sName
End If
If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "elephant") <> 0 Then
    sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "elephant", "e5...")
    fil.Name = sName
End If
If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "fan") <> 0 Then
    sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "fan", "f6...")
    fil.Name = sName
End If
If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "guitar") <> 0 Then
    sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "guitar", "g7...")
    fil.Name = sName
End If
If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "hat") <> 0 Then
    sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "hat", "h8....")
    fil.Name = sName
End If
If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "ink") <> 0 Then
    sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "ink", "i9...")
    fil.Name = sName
End If
If InStr(Lcase(fil.Name), "jet") <> 0 Then
    sName = Replace(Lcase(fil.Name), "jet", "j10...")
    fil.Name = sName
End If

Next

     End Sub

     Sub Progress
     x = x + 1
     document.Title = FormatPercent(x / y, 0) & MyTitle
     document.all.ProgBarText.innerText = x & "/" & y
     document.all.ProgBarDone.innerText = String(x, "_")
     document.all.ProgBarToDo.innerText = String(y - x, "_") & "|"
    If x = y Then
     document.all.ProgBarToDo.innerText = ""
    MsgBox "Done"
    window.close
     End If
     End Sub
  </SCRIPT>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#D7D7D7">

  Path:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="path">
  <br>

  <br>
  <!-- Basic buttons -->
  <input id="BtnGo" type="button" value="Go" onclick="Go">
  <br>
  <span id="ProgBarText"></span>
  <br>
  <span id="ProgBarDone" style="background-color: #3399FF"></span>
  <font color="#FFFFFF">
 <span id="ProgBarToDo"style="background-color: #C0C0C0"></span>
 </font>
</body>

</html>
```

This code successfully renames all the relevant file names in just the parent folder. However I still don't see an increasing progress bar and the file number being processed while the hta runs, until the end. After all the files are renamed, it shows the progress bar at the end like this:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhcrO.jpg)

I would like to know:
 - How to make the progress-bar to stay visible  and update accordingly
   while  the files are being processed by the script and 
 - A way to include files from subfolders in the parent folder as well for renaming by the script

New Method:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title id="title">Rename</title>
  <HTA:APPLICATION ID="ProgressBar" APPLICATIONNAME="ProgressBar"
   SCROLL="no" MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no" />
  
   <SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
    
    Sub Window_Onload
     window.resizeTo 250, 180
    End Sub
  
 Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 Dim sSDir : sSDir = "C:\Users\my\Desktop\sections_2_3"

 walkDirIter goFS.GetFolder(sSDir)

 Sub walkDirIter(oDir)
 Dim dicStack : Set dicStack = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 Dim nCur     : nCur         = dicStack.Count
 Set dicStack(nCur) = oDir
 Do Until nCur >= dicStack.Count
    Dim oElm
    For Each oElm In dicStack(nCur).Files
  
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "apple") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "apple", "a1...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "ball") <> 0 Then
    sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "ball", "b2...")
    oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "cat") <> 0 Then
    sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "cat", "c3....")
    oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "dog") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "dog", "d4....")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "elephant") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "elephant", "e5...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "fan") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "fan", "f6...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "guitar") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "guitar", "g7...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "hat") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "hat", "h8....")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "ink") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "ink", "i9...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "jet") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "jet", "j10...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
 Next
 
    For Each oElm In dicStack(nCur).SubFolders
  Set dicStack(dicStack.Count) = oElm
    Next
     nCur = nCur + 1
 Loop
 
 End Sub

  </SCRIPT>

       
</head>

<body bgcolor="#D7D7D7">

  Path:
  <br>
  
  <input type="text" name="Path">
 
  <br>

  <br>
  <!-- Basic buttons -->
  <input id="BtnGo" type="button" value="Go" onclick="walkDirIter(oDir)">
  <br>
  
 </font>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried this [New Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214927/vbs-show-all-folder-subfolders-with-an-iterative-script?rq=1) to skip the repetition of same code for folders and subfolders separately. This method is easy and compact.

Working VB script:

```html
 Dim str
 set str = Wscript.Arguments

 str = InputBox("Enter the path of the files to be renamed as per e-ctd naming pattern")
 IF str = "" THEN Cancelled

 Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 Dim sSDir : sSDir = str

 walkDirIter goFS.GetFolder(sSDir)

 Sub walkDirIter(oDir)
 Dim dicStack : Set dicStack = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 Dim nCur     : nCur         = dicStack.Count
 Set dicStack(nCur) = oDir
 Do Until nCur >= dicStack.Count
    Dim oElm
    For Each oElm In dicStack(nCur).Files
  
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "apple") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "apple", "a1...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "ball") <> 0 Then
    sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "ball", "b2...")
    oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "cat") <> 0 Then
    sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "cat", "c3....")
    oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "dog") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "dog", "d4....")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "elephant") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "elephant", "e5...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "fan") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "fan", "f6...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "guitar") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "guitar", "g7...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "hat") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "hat", "h8....")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "ink") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "ink", "i9...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
  If InStr(Lcase(oElm.Name), "jet") <> 0 Then
   sName = Replace(Lcase(oElm.Name), "jet", "j10...")
   oElm.Name = sName
  End If
 Next
 
    For Each oElm In dicStack(nCur).SubFolders
  Set dicStack(dicStack.Count) = oElm
    Next
     nCur = nCur + 1
 Loop
 
 End Sub
```

Comment: I have started working on this. There are quite a few syntax errors. Did you ever have it working without the progress bar code in it? I think it would be advantageous to make a script using the minimum needed to make changes to one folder, then after that works, add the sub-folder changes and finally the progress bar.

Comment: You have some things out of order. You are calling the sub "ShowSubFolders" before "path.value" has been keyed into the HTA, so that is failing as well.

Comment: @RandySchuman Thanks and Sorry for the mistake. The script started giving syntax error after I tried to TIDY it using insert HTML option before posting. So this time i did not tidy it up and its working. Now it runs and renames all the files in the parent folder. I have also corrected the value of X and Y to zero as it was giving incorrect total files value. I also get a full progress bar (100%) at the end, after the script finishes renaming all the files.

Comment: @RandySchuman I was thinking that it will call _Sub ShowSubFolders_ only when the user clicks on the button **GO** after entering the path. I was obviously wrong. How should I reorder it. Please suggest.

Comment: I would take a step back an take a minimalist approach. Create a script in VBScript only and make it work making a fixed folder for testing and assigning that as a variable near the top of the script. Once that works, add the subfolder process to it. I noticed in your HTA that the window is very large and the input box in on the top left. You can change the html code to make it smaller and have the input box centered in the window. Once you have the hta working where it saves the input as a variable, just insert the vbscript in the proper place and pass the variable to it.

Comment: Don't even worry about subs or functions in the script yet, just make it work linear for now. After your feeling confident with the code, you can then mod it to have subs or functions to be more correct. The final stage would be adding the progress bar. There are several methods on the internet for this. All of the things you are doing in the hta/vbs are very common and the information is abundant on the web.

Comment: I have removed the Progress bar from the New Method (edited and posted above) and set the path to a fixed folder. But as soon as I run this HTA the VBscript in it renames all the files in folders and subfolders without giving any error, which is obvious as the path has been set to one folder like you suggested. But I could not figure out how to make the HTA wait till user inputs the path and click on GO before it moves to VBscript part.Please help.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. What I meant to say that the HTA automatically runs the VBscript which picks up the files from the already set path and renames them. I want it to wait till I click on GO button before it processes the file names.

Comment: Once the vbscript is added to the HTA, you should have removed the fixed path and replaced it with the variable being set from the input.

Comment: I replaced the fixed path with variable _"Path.value"_ but it gives an error _Path not found_ and asks if I want to continue running script. Once I Ignore the error and continue the script and enter the path in input box manually, and then click on **GO** button, it gives another error _Object required 'dicStack'_. How to get past this?

Comment: I suggested that you get the VBScript working OUTSIDE of the HTA first. By the errors you are getting it appears you did not do that.

Comment: I did it the way you said it. I made the VBscript first and then put it in HTA. I have added my fully working VBscript above.