# Batch file to move all files whose file NAME contains a future date (YYYYMMDD) to a seperate folder

Tags: batch-file, dos

I need a batch file that will take any files in a given folder with a value for YYYYMMDD **within their name, GREATER than today's date** (for some reasonable range into the future) and move them to another folder.

```
set MainFolder=..\
set FutureFolder=.\
set FutureDaysToCount=90
set today=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%
```

%today% in the above example will give me (on May 30, 2012): 20120530

What I want to do is loop **dates** from %today% TO %today% + %FutureDaysToCount% and execute:

```
move *yyyymmdd*.txt .\SomeOtherFolder
```

...for every day in the 90 day range, where **yyyymmdd** would be the numerical equivalent of the current date being processed.  So:

```
move *20120530*.txt .\SomeOtherFolder
move *20120531*.txt .\SomeOtherFolder
move *20120601*.txt .\SomeOtherFolder  REM note new month here!
```

Is there a way to increment days within a loop to accomplish this?

### NOTE

This is similar, but different from:
[Batch process to move file having Date in YYYYMMDD format from one folder to another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937944/batch-process-to-move-file-having-date-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-one-folder-to-ano)

Comment: Do your files have any more a specific format than `*yyyymmdd*.txt`?  I.e., is the date consistently at the start or end of the file name?

Comment: The date could be anywhere, and there's nothing more specific.  AND, I can't touch files with PAST dates.

Answer (score 2):

Use WMIC to get today's date (works regardless of locale).

Then use julian date functions found at http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsDateTime.php to compute your date strings in a loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "skip=1" %%D in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do set dt=%%D&goto :break
:break
call :date2jdate jdStart %dt:~0,4% %dt:~4,2% %dt:~6,2%
set /a jdEnd=jdStart+90
for /l %%N in (%jdStart% 1 %jdEnd%) do (
  call :jdate2date %%N yyyy mm dd
  move "*!yyyy!!mm!!dd!*.txt" ".\SomeOtherFolder"
)
exit /b

:date2jdate JD YYYY MM DD -- converts a gregorian calender date to julian day format
::                        -- JD   [out] - julian days
::                        -- YYYY [in]  - gregorian year, i.e. 2006
::                        -- MM   [in]  - gregorian month, i.e. 12 for december
::                        -- DD   [in]  - gregorian day, i.e. 31
:$reference http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/JD_Formula.html
:$created 20060101 :$changed 20080219 :$categories DateAndTime
:$source http://www.dostips.com
SETLOCAL
set "yy=%~2"&set "mm=%~3"&set "dd=%~4"
set /a "yy=10000%yy% %%10000,mm=100%mm% %% 100,dd=100%dd% %% 100"
if %yy% LSS 100 set /a yy+=2000 &rem Adds 2000 to two digit years
set /a JD=dd-32075+1461*(yy+4800+(mm-14)/12)/4+367*(mm-2-(mm-14)/12*12)/12-3*((yy+4900+(mm-14)/12)/100)/4
ENDLOCAL & IF "%~1" NEQ "" (SET %~1=%JD%) ELSE (echo.%JD%)
EXIT /b

:jdate2date JD YYYY MM DD -- converts julian days to gregorian date format
::                     -- JD   [in]  - julian days
::                     -- YYYY [out] - gregorian year, i.e. 2006
::                     -- MM   [out] - gregorian month, i.e. 12 for december
::                     -- DD   [out] - gregorian day, i.e. 31
:$reference http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/JD_Formula.html
:$created 20060101 :$changed 20080219 :$categories DateAndTime
:$source http://www.dostips.com
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a L= %~1+68569,     N= 4*L/146097, L= L-(146097*N+3)/4, I= 4000*(L+1)/1461001
set /a L= L-1461*I/4+31, J= 80*L/2447,  K= L-2447*J/80,      L= J/11
set /a J= J+2-12*L,      I= 100*(N-49)+I+L
set /a YYYY= I,  MM=100+J,  DD=100+K
set MM=%MM:~-2%
set DD=%DD:~-2%
( ENDLOCAL & REM RETURN VALUES
    IF "%~2" NEQ "" (SET %~2=%YYYY%) ELSE echo.%YYYY%
    IF "%~3" NEQ "" (SET %~3=%MM%) ELSE echo.%MM%
    IF "%~4" NEQ "" (SET %~4=%DD%) ELSE echo.%DD%
)
EXIT /b
```

Comment: Nothing to be scared of :-) If you want to test non-destructively, simply put ECHO before the MOVE and run - it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The Batch file below do what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set FutureDaysToCount=90

rem Get parts of current date and set number of days by month
set year=%DATE:~10,4%
set MM=%DATE:~4,2%
set DD=%DATE:~7,2%
set /A month=1%MM% %% 100, day=1%DD% %% 100
set i=0
for %%d in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set days[!i!]=%%d
)
if %month% lss 3 (
   rem Check if current year is leap
   set /A leapYear=year %% 4
) else (
   rem Check if next year is leap
   set /A "leapYear=(year+1) %% 4"
)   
if %leapYear% equ 0 set days[2]=29
set daysThisMonth=!days[%month%]!

rem Loop through the dates for the number of days
for /L %%i in (1,1,%FutureDaysToCount%) do (
   rem Advance the date to next day
   set /A day+=1
   if !day! gtr !daysThisMonth! (
      rem Advance the date to next month
      set /A month+=1, day=1
      if !month! gtr 12 (
         rem Advance the date to next year
         set /A year+=1, month=1
      )
      call :setElem daysThisMonth=days[!month!]
      set MM=!month!
      if !month! lss 10 set MM=0!month!
   )
   set DD=!day!
   if !day! lss 10 set DD=0!day!

   rem Execute the desired command:
   ECHO move *!year!!MM!!DD!*.txt SomeOtherFolder
)
goto :EOF

:setElem var=vector[!index!]
set %1=!%2!
exit /B
```

This Batch file may be easily modified to be independent of locale date settings using the method described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207723/vbscript-how-to-sort-files-in-subfolders-by-modified-date-and-print-it-with-the/10222334#10222334)

Comment: Didn't work for me as written, even after accounting for locale differences. First SET /A fails if month or day = 08 or 09. Should be converted to 3 individual SET statements without /A option. Leap year SET /A with parentheses must be quoted, or escape the right paren.

Comment: It dies on me in here, no idea why: if %month% lss 3 (
   rem Check if current year is leap
   set /A leapYear=year %% 4
pause
) else (
   rem Check if next year is leap
   set /A leapYear=(year+1) %% 4
pause
)

Comment: dbenham: Yes, you are right! (I wrote it at 2 am :-). @tbone: Copy it again, the problem was solved...